# SciTE Java run subpackages

Tags: java, package, scite

I'm using SciTE to write a small amount of Java at the moment. Only stuff to learn the language basics etc. At the moment I have a base directory, Java, a sub directory, practice, which has 2 subdirectories, running & testing. When I use the "build" command in SciTE I've managed to set that up to work. But what I cannot get working is the Java\practice\testing\ModelTester class (practice.testing package) to run. I get a NoClassDefFoundException and a wrong name message.

I know that the problem is the I need to run:

```
java practice.testing.ModelTester
```

but how do I get this into the command.go.*.java section of the SciTEDirectory.properties (in the Java directory). Obviously I would like something to put in command.go.*.java that can apply to any and every Java file I might run in a package.